# Moving webform uploads to a non-public folderspace

Tags: webforms

On Drupal 6, I have a `webform` that needs to collect file uploads. I can do this of course through the `File` type. However, I'd like to not leave these files sitting in a folder visible to Apache.

Using the following

```
hook_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) { 
        print_r($node);
        die();
    }
```

I can see the following data structure.

```
        [components] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [nid] => 156117
                        [cid] => 1
                        [form_key] => test
                        [name] => TEST
                        [type] => file
                        [value] => 
                        [extra] => Array
                            (
                                [savelocation] => creative/samples
                                [title_display] => before
                                [private] => 0
                                [filtering] => Array
                                    (
                                        [size] => 800
                                        [types] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => gif
                                                [1] => jpg
                                                [2] => png
                                            )

                                        [addextensions] => 
                                    )
```

In the `[extra][savelocation]`, could I modify this to a folder that is not accessible via apache? How would I properly update the database entry?

Comment: I've tried the module Webform Private Upload with no luck. I was able to see my test image via http://server/sites/default/files/webform/private/test.jpg