# Are there hook_functions to handle submissions from the webforms module in Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, hooks, webforms

I'm asking this question as a possible way to handle another issue I possted about ("[Moving webform uploads to a non-public folderspace](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105148)"). Is there a hook_function that I can use to handle the submission of a [webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) in Drupal 6. That is, can I use a `hook` to relocate a file uploaded through a webform ***and*** update the database entry to mark that upload files new place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these three hooks.

- [hook_webform_submission_presave()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/6) - which is called before saving.
- [hook_webform_submission_update()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_update/6) -  which is called after the submission is stored in database
- [hook_webform_submission_actions()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_actions/6) - which provides a list of actions that can be executed on a submission.